# What is the right ordering of words depending upon the worth that they imply? Also, can you suggest me some more words?

Tags: sort-ordering

Can you suggest me some words to complete the following ordering of words based on the worth which they imply. I would ideally like a list of around 5-7 words

1. cheap
2. affordable
3. ???
4. expensive

What word should be used to describe an item which has an average price?

Also, where in the order would value-for-money, economical fit in?

Comment: Are informal words allowed?

Comment: yes. the more commonly used the words are, the better.

Comment: There is no single way to order them, as these words do not represent degrees (e.g. the difference between *good, better, best*) but reflect different concepts, with different connotations (e.g. the difference between *swept*, *rinsed*, and *scrubbed*). As such, it will be largely a matter of opinion as to whether *discount* is cheaper than *low-cost* and so on. There is no single word for something average-priced, either, because there are many kind sof "average" prices, for instance *retail price* as opposed to *street price*.

Answer (score 1):

For the last two in your sequence, how about:

4. Luxurious
5. Exclusive

Answer (score 1):

For item 3, I'd suggest "midrange", or maybe "competitive", though that last seems a little jargony.

For the last item in the list, I'd suggest "top-of-the-line" or "top-shelf" or maybe "elite".

Comment: Also, "deluxe" is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a try, using all other suggestions.

1. Cheap (especially in comparison to other similar services)
2. Economical (more of an "absolute")
3. Competitive
4. Affordable
5. Mid-range
6. Pricey
7. Costly
8. Expensive
9. Luxurious
10. High-End

Edit: this is an INFORMAL ranking, i.e., it expresses my personal opinions on this and some of these words come from different contexts.
Keep also in mind that a few of these words (especially 6-7-8) are usually listed as synonyms.